# Auto Start OTR on pidgin

Tags: instant-messaging

I'm using Pidgin on Windows with OTR. I want to know if it's possible to "auto-start" OTR using the buddy pounce feature on Pidgin (or on all conversations would work too).

Comment: @schroeder sorry, I really wasn't sure where to put it.